# Automatically attach app extension to debugger

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension

I'm just wondering if there is an easy way to have my app extension attached to debugger after the containing app is launched. So right now I hit run button then go to Debug menu and attach my process. Is there a way to automate this process to have my app extension attached after I run the containing app?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there are no other solutions than the one mentioned in the question